# Mystery none working power outlets

Tags: electrical

I have a split entry home that on the lower level 5 outlets in the family room only have gone out. One inside on stair wall to front plugs and 3 on end fireplace wall. We had an electrician doing the checking and 5 hours with no solution. We have taken out all plugs and tested all of them, checked circuit panel and plus on other rooms as well.

Comment: Just to check, they worked previously? Did anything happen at the time they stopped working?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. @SomeoneSomewhere is right: we'll need more info; please edit it into your question.

Comment: Were they wired by looping wires around the screws, or sticking wires into the back of the receptacle?

Comment: Are there any other outlets (sockets, lamps etc.) on that same circuit that still work?